# Narrow union type dynamically (change `switch` for `object`)

Tags: typescript

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOA3BAJCBDewBGHgFkIBnI9Ac2gF4oBvAWACgopRIAuKAIgAsMtd0wTo2boAxsACWAewB2HAORhJssgsYBfRo1bQ4SBAElZRYPACuAWwizgRQiXJVaIluAgdOK0xeu2inAA0ruJScp5EsuhgRNzSQpraDLpQDqQUUJSuAD6wCMjwaJg4eGlOOXkG8MY%20VjZ2ZRRJYnKmUNzosgAmADYQjc4AFNaOFBwDAJSZAHwuTFBEAO6SwGLcUMPE6RAAdLpT9PPMYuhE0Aq8xQLAChyHzA9QkgBmGyPbO6EyspmU1EoqNQHVyPY6taR9HY9aRkQacIr8PBBKDvJwTEGg7DwDAAawA3BjmFojg8sbiCSTiY8TmcoApvGY6v5bnNQU9XptRrsvnJfv9ItFYvEFMCSdTwZDobDODVGX5gAsojE4kJAiitmjCVAqZjseh8RidcTiYwAPSmqAAdU6CuA0gWy1W6ztUHQUGh0hx5jAUGk2AAVhAJIwWiYFR1un14ERMqz2nwSoI7hjlKoOMMiGQppRZqGiBDdlKM1nXBpgvMGb56kRkySBcr4unLJns7mJYWYcX0fNjSHWuHOr1%20hqKAAmWOc7bjEcQVtx81Wm0se0enFQb0sXjtQdRqDPeDSSyb6ARofR30BoPAVynqNEADaqIoe3cAF0APw7R8zz4Sb4fnZJ01BgNCAA)

I currently have a `switch/case` statement which handles incoming messages from a WS.

Snippet:

```js
const handleMessage = (message: Message) => {
  switch (message.type) {
    case 'heartbeat': {
      if (message.action === 'ping') {
        console.log("Heartbeat", message)
        break;
      }
...
```

I'd like to migrate it to use an object which defines handles for each incoming message type.

Snippet:

```js
// Want to switch to a lookup object
const handlers = {
  heartbeat: {
    ping: (msg) => console.log(msg)
  },
...
const handleMessage2 = (message: Message) => {
  // Want to look up the handler from the handlers object
  handlers[message.type]?.[message.action]?.(message)
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to type my message handlers correctly so the parameter of the message handler is narrowed in the same way as the `switch/case` version.

Comment: ① Please [edit] the code in the question to include all relevant code as plaintext here, so that it's a [mre]. The playground link is very helpful but the code should also be here in the question directly. I'd do the edit for you but I don't have copyright on externally displayed code. ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/we8pdW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution courtesy of @Retsam19. A combination of mapped object types and `Extract`

```
type LookupObject = {
  [Type in Message["type"]]: Record<Extract<Message, { type: Type }>["action"], (msg: Extract<Message, { type: Type}>) => void>
}

const handlers: LookupObject = {
  heartbeat: {
    ping: (msg) => console.log(msg)
  },
  instruments: {
    snapshot: (msg) => console.log(msg)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses your question; inside your `handleMessage2` function [the same error occurs with these typings](https://tsplay.dev/mM74rw).  Could you please [edit] to elaborate about exactly how this constitutes a solution to the problem you described above?